# MySQL: What is the best way to store user_type and user_type_id?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I created 3 tables for store users, students and examiners.

**Users table contain login details**

```
id
name
email
password
user_type (3 user types: 1 - administrators, 2 - students, 3 - examiners) 
user_type_id
```

> If user_type == 2 or 3, then based on that value, user_type_id field get
>   student id  or examiner id, if user_type == 1 then value == 0.

**students table contain student details**

```
id
name
age
birthday
```

**examiners table contain examiners details**

```
id
name
age
qualifications
```

my question is, is it ok to use above way to link users, students and examiners?

If not please suggest a way. Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion: isn't it better to put a `user_id` in the tables `students` and `examiners`? instead of having a reference from `users` to `students`/`examiners`, the other way around.

Comment: there can be a little optimization if you plan to have a lot of records (no real use for you to optimize at this point if tables are not huge or structure is not meant to change). The concept is to assemble in `users` all data that are common to all people (`name` and `age`). Then instead of having fixed tables for variations (students/examiners), you can have a single table `details` with `id` (indexing) `user_id`, `field_type` or `field_id`. The 3rd column depends if your structure is fixed (type) or dynamic (id). If dynamic, you'd have a third table recensing those fields, you can then add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**: your data model needs some improvements.

1. You put **age** attribute and birthday attribute in Student. Adding age in database is incorrect. You should **use only birthday**. Same problem in Examiners.
2. The best practice for designing data model for Information Systems with **Authentication** (and Authorization) is to **separate them** into 2 modules in Data Model. AA module and Other parts of Information System. This separation has som advantages like extendability of your whole system and usabilty of AA in other systems and etc.
3. Another improvement is to define a new Entity named **UserType** and use the foreign key in Users entity.
4. When you use both Student ID and Examiner ID in one attribute in Users entity, your model is **not Normal** and you can not set foreign keys.

**Secondly**: To provide a data model

we have relationships between Users and two other entities (Student and Examiners). Maybe in future other entities added to this list.

 We have 2 relationships: 
one relation between Users and Student and another relation between User and Examiner 
**These relationships are one-to-one**. For example each Student has one User and each User can be set for only one Student. And similar statement between User and Examine.

**In one-to-one relationships we have 2 solutions:** 

1- pass primary key of Entity at side 1 in 1-1 relationship as foreign key to 
Entity of side 2. 
2- pass primary key of Entity at side 2 in 1-1 relationship as foreign key to 
Entity of side 1.

Both solutions are true and Normal. So we have 2 solutions for this case:

**Solution 1**: transfer User ID as foreign key to both Student and Examiner. In this solution we can easily find each User ID of specific Student or specific Examiner. **But** the hard part of this solution is finding a Student or Examiner based on User ID. Answer is: Notice that we have User Type for each User ID. So based on User Type of User ID, we know which table to be search (Student or Examiner).

**Solution 2**: transfer both Student and Examiner IDs as foreign keys into Users. Meaning that User Entity have 2 foreign key. First for Student ID and Second for Examiner ID. This solution seams so effective. But it conflict Modularity of AA Module (Authentication and Authorization Module). Another problem emerge when the number of other tables (Student, Examiner,...) that have relation with User is HIGH.  Anyway, in small Information Systems we can use this solution.